# MathJax.Hub.getAllJax returns empty array

Tags: javascript, jquery, angularjs, mathjax

My html:

`<span id="questiondisplay">{{question_display}}</span`>

Javascript code:

```
var math = MathJax.Hub.getAllJax("questiondisplay")
```

On doing this math is an empty array `[]`

However, on doing `$('#questiondisplay')` I get: `[<span id="questiondisplay" class="ng-binding"></span>]`

Can anyone please explain what I'm doing wrong with MathJax ?

Comment: There is no math inside the element with id `question display`.  You say you get `[<span id="questiondisplay" class="ng-binding"></span>]`, which is an empty span, so it contains no math.  So asking MathJax to get all the math that is inside it *should* return an empty array.  Maybe you should say what you are trying to do in more detail, and what result you *expect* to get.

Comment: Looks like something is attempting to process the double curly braces `{{ }}` before the HTML hits the page. Could be your templating engine (Angular? Handlebars?) Try configuring MathJax to use a different delimiter. Double dollar signs `$$ $$` seems like a common choice.